# sql server with different database of different time zone. how to get getdatetime for all database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 databases, each in different time zone.
How do I get the date and time of all these with `GetDateTime`.

Usually we get the Server time, but I need the Date and time of the databases

Comment: What is the difference between server time and database time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2008 or later you can take a look on

[SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx)  and [SWITCHOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx)

Generally the first is returning the system datetime with the TimeZone offset part like -07:00 and the second can calculate a time based on datetimeoffset and a timezone offset property.

Since **there is no database level setting** for time-zones you should find an other solution.

If you would like to manage an application in the **same SQL Server** but for **4 different** database with the correct time-zone for each, I think the best way to make a SystemSetting (the name is not important) table where you can save the offset. Then you can use the SWITCHOFFSET to calculate the correct time for the given database by each query where you need.

Or you can try to use virtual-machines.

Comment: Is there any settings that can be done in the database, so when i want to get the date time , i get the timezone one correctly.      thanks..

Comment: No, what you can do to make a setting table and save this info there. (the offset), and then you can write the same queries for all, which is getting that value from the table and calculating with it. With this solution you can manage the timezones.

Comment: Ok.But I am looking for any settings that can be done in the database server . as i cannot change the code now. thanks

Comment: There is no way (no setting) to do this. If you can't change the code then try to solve it with virtual-machines, because on the same server and on the same instance you won't achive that.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. Is it possible to get date and time(with the timezone factor) for one database alone without coding?

Comment: Yes but it is NOT for the database BUT for the SQL Server Instance based on the system time of the OS. As I wrote this method is the SYSDATETIMEOFFSET

Answer (score 2):

If these are SQL 2008 servers or later...

```
select sysutcdatetime()
```

Comment: sysutcdatetime() is getting the GMT, and the OP needs different timezones. It won't help him.