# SQL Server regional settings database wise

Tags: sql-server, database, configuration, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SQL Server instance with 3 databases.  (A, B & C).

The operating system has regional / date & time settings of India.

**My requirement is  :**

Database A should get regional settings of India.

Database B should get regional settings of US.

Database C should get regional settings of Dubai.

Currently, I am concerned with date & time only.

So, If I execute the query on the different databases:

```
Select getdate()
```

It should return the date & time based on the database's regional setting (which i am trying to find how to set).

For Eg : The Operating System's Current Date & Time is 3rd November  6:18 pm

Database A (India Time) should Give 3rd November  6:18 pm

Database B (US Time) should Give 3rd November  7:49 pm

Database C (Dubai Time) should Give 3rd November  4:49 pm

I am unsure about how do I change the settings database wise from server or by passing some parameters via connection string or is it really possible to accomplish this.

or I would have to write my own function for doing this.

Comment: There is no database level setting for time-zones in SQL Server, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293036/sql-server-with-different-database-of-different-time-zone-how-to-get-getdatetim

Comment: That sounds like a deeply wrong design. If you're starting to concern yourself with multiple regions/cultures, it's usually time to start using a single fixed culture in the database (e.g. all times recorded as UTC) and then adapt to different cultures at the UI layer.

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you should use `SELECT GETUTCDATE()`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The three databases have no connection/relation to each other. even the applications which will use them are different. It is just that I dont want to have 3 machines with different sql server installed in them for such a small thing..

Comment: Does the software using the DBs not have options for timezones?

Comment: @Burgi The software(s) has no such thing as of now.

Comment: There is not much redunancy if this server goes down or has an issue. You will have users in three countries unable to work.